# Enum.TryParse: Is there a guarantee or contract for the out parameter value when the return value is `false`?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, tryparse, base-class-library

According to [the documentation for `Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), if the method returns false, it will set the out parameter to zero.  I do not see a similar guarantee for Enum.TryParse in [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It seems that there *ought* to be such a guarantee, because the method has to set the out parameter to *something*, and zero makes the most sense.

Is the guarantee specified or documented somewhere else, or is there really no guarantee?

Comment: Why not try it? But I would guess it probably just comes out null

Comment: As you point out, the method has to set the out parameter to *something*. I think that's your answer; you have a guarantee that the out parameter will be set to *something*.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I did try it, and it comes out zero -- it can't come out null because it is a non-nullable value type.  I want to know whether there's a guarantee, because, if there isn't, I should assume that the behavior could change in future versions of the framework.

Comment: Why would you rely on the value if the parsing didn't work? Maybe you could set it to zero yourself after the parsing failed, if you're interested in this scenario. Or, you could create a method that returns an [option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type), so as to force clients _not_ to use the result when the parsing doesn't work.

Comment: This seems like a good example of something you shouldn't rely on, even if it is guaranteed somewhere, just in terms of code readability/maintainability.  It may not be clear that your code relies on this implementation.

Comment: @Jordão *I* wouldn't rely on the value if the parsing didn't work, but, unfortunately, one of my coworkers wrote a method that does.  In this code, the correct thing to do if the parse fails is probably to throw an exception (so we should be using `Parse` anyway).  I'm weighing whether (and how) to bring this up to my bosses.

Comment: @Servy I definitely agree with you. In this case, I'm trying to determine the presence or absence of a guarantee because that will affect whether and how I approach my coworkers with some code that ignores the return value of TryParse.

Comment: Even if it's not guaranteed, it's a good bet that the current behavior isn't going to change, since it wouldn't really make sense and could break existing code.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque that's very true, but I wouldn't want to count on it in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't expect it to be guaranteed to be be anything more specific than "something". Since documentation does not specify otherwise (and it is the only official documentation) just use return value, but ignore out parameter if return is false.

Side note: I think it is wrong that Int32.TryParse specifies what out parameter is set to if parsing failed as one should make own decisions what "not really a number" means in each particular case... But it is my personal opinion.

Comment: +1 I am inclined to agree with you, and if I were writing the code that prompted this question, I wouldn't even be asking. The code is in a part of the code base I'm not working on directly; it uses the value of the out parameter without checking the method's return value.  I am debating whether it's worth the effort to bring it to my boss's attention to get permission to change it.  Not changing it would be more defensible if the behavior with a `false` return were guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

> If value is a name that does not correspond to a named constant of
>   TEnum, the method returns false. If value is the string representation
>   of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the TEnum
>   enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying
>   value is value converted to an integral type. If this behavior is
>   undesirable, call the IsDefined method to ensure that a particular
>   string representation of an integer is actually a member of TEnum.

So I would absolutely NOT rely on the value of `out` in case the call comes back with `false`!

Comment: +1 I agree with you.  The code that prompted this question doesn't check the method's return; it just uses the out argument variable, and I'm debating whether to bring this up with my bosses.  If the parsed value is guaranteed to be zero on failure, I could see how that would affect our calling method, and maybe it wouldn't be necessary to go to the trouble of creating a change request, etc.